# How to sets a range of cells as condition for If Statement in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm a beginner in Excel vba and I'm working on code that can help me to create a comment and highlight the cell automatically when a certain supplier id is entered. I normally do it manually but found that a vba will save a lot of time when there are loads of data to be entered.

I know that I can do it with If Or statement to create multiple conditions, but when there's new supplier Id, I need to go back to code and add a new condition into the IF Statement.

So, I'm thinking to create a sheet called "Variables" and I can save the variables inside and add a new variable into the sheet. By using the IF statement and recall the conditions from a range of cells that are stored in "Variable" sheet, but it just able to set the A2 cell as the condition and didn't set the others' in A3, A4, A5 as multiple conditions.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCell As Range, Rg As Range
    Dim Supplier As Range, Rg1 As Range
    Dim Vendor_id As Range, Rg2 As Range
    Dim i As Long, startRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    startRow = 2
    LastRow = 10
    
    On Error Resume Next

    Set Rg1 = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C65536"))    'Set Range for Supplier
    Set Rg2 = Application.Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Variables").Range("A2:A4")) 'Set Ranges for supplier in Variables sheet as condition
    Set Rg3 = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B65536"))     'Range for Alert Window          
       If Not Rg1 Is Nothing Then
        For Each Supplier In Rg1

             For i = startRow To LastRow
             
             If Supplier.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Variables").Range("A" & i) Then
            
                    Supplier.Interior.Color = 24567               'Automatic fill in the cells with orange colour if Supplier id is met the criteria
                    
                    ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=-1, ColumnOffset:=2).Activate  'Select and activate the cell of the desired column on the respective row
                    
                    'Insert the file path Hyperlink into the selected cell and change the font type of the Hyperlink
                   With ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Range(ActiveCell.Address), Address:="https://www.automateexcel.com/excel/", TextToDisplay:="Checking needed")
                        .Range.Font.Bold = True
                        .Range.Font.Underline = False
                        .Range.Font.Color = vbMagenta                        
                    End With           
             Else
                    Supplier.Interior.Color = 16777215            'Clear the Colour in the cells if the value is nothing              
              End If
              Exit Sub
              Next i
          Exit Sub
          Next Supplier
        End If
             
        If Not Rg3 Is Nothing Then
        For Each xCell In Rg3                                    'Create a dialog to ask  Check for certain parts
            If xCell.Value = "Cardboard" Or xCell.Value = "Toolkit" Then
              Dim int2 As Integer
                int2 = MsgBox("Please send an email to notify", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Quality Alert")
                                         
                 xCell.Interior.Color = 2552550  'Highlight the cells with Yellow Colour
                 
            Else
                
                 xCell.Interior.Color = 16777215  'Clear the Colour in the cellsFOdfdfsdsdfsd if the value is nothing
                              
                Exit Sub
            End If
         Next
       End If
       
       End Sub
```

I thought I could use the For loop using increment by 1 on the Variables Range in order to create multiple conditions on every loop, but it didn't play out.

I've been searching through the whole website to find a solution and some site says that .Value just only able to read 1 value at a time and not possible to read multiple range of values.

Is it possible to select a range of cells in the worksheet to become the multiple conditions for IF statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worksheet_Change will run each time you change a cell.  So, you only need it to make changes to cells in *the same row* as you the end user just changed.  You are currently looping through all of ranges Rg1 and Rg3 with each cell change, which is undesirable.

From your description, I cannot tell what is in the various ranges.  For this explanation:

- A2:A4 contains a list of special suppliers, which you should move to a separate worksheet from the sheet containing the main data table.
- A8:A9 contains the list of special materials (Cardboard and Toolkit), which you should move to a separate worksheet from the sheet containing the main data table.
- Columns B through D contain the data:

  - Column B: Alert
  - Column C: Supplier
  - Column D: Material

In this scenario, whenever we update a cell in columns B through E (except the first row), we want to check the supplier (col C) and material (col D).  If the supplier matches an entry in A2:A4, then highlight it and add a hyperlink in Column B.  If the material matches a material in A8:A9, then highlight it.

You can really do all of this (except inserting a hyperlink) without VBA by using VLookup and Conditional Formatting.  However, I'll address the VBA approach, as it is worthwhile.

I will use Format as Table to address the issue of a potentially changing or growing list of conditions (Suppliers and Materials) that you may want to trigger the check.  Format as Table is not about formatting, but about dynamically sizing tables and calling on their data much like a database.  You can read a bit here: https://www.intheblack.com/articles/2018/08/01/understand-excel-format-as-table-icon.  The Format as Table feature will allow you to change the number of conditions, which you refer to as Cells A2:A5 without having to change any code!  Let's look at an example.

1. On a different sheet than your main data sheet, in Range A1 enter the title "Special Suppliers"
2. In range A2:A5 list your 4 special conditions that result in highlighting.
3. Select A1:A5.
4. From the Home ribbon, select Format as Table.  When prompted, check the box to indicate the table has a header.
5. This is now named range 'Table1'.  Let's go to the Table Design ribbon, and change the name to 'SpecialSupplierTable'.
6. Repeat steps1-5 to create a 'SpecialMaterialTable' with a header in C1 and data in C2:C3.
7. On the main data sheet, Highlight all of the main data table and Format as Table with name 'DataTable'.

You can now add and remove rows to any of these ranges freely.  As you do, the named range will automatically resize.  No need to change your code!

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Excel automatically sets the Target argument.
    ' Target is a Range object that references the changed Cell.
    Dim msg As String
    
    
    ' Don't remove this, or the next failure will disable event handling,
    ' which means the macro will not run again.
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    ' It is important to disable and reenable event handling.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    
    ' Only run this if the changed data is within the confines
    ' of the DataTable.
    If RangeAContainsRangeB([DataTable], Target) Then
    
        Call ApplyAlertFormatting(Target)
        
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    Exit Sub
EH:
    ' In the even of an error, enable event handling.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    ' If you really want, you can comment out the next line
    ' to prevent error messaging, but I don't recommend it.
    Title = "Error " & Err.Number
    msg = "Error Sheet1.Worksheet_Change().  Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    MsgBox msg, vbCritical, Title, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub


Function ApplyAlertFormatting(Target As Range)
    Dim Supplier As Range
    Dim Material As Range
    Dim alertCell As Range
    Dim supplierCell As Range
    Dim materialCell As Range

    Set alertCell = Cells(Target.Row, [DataTable[Alert]].Column) ' Column B, the same row as the updated cell
    Set supplierCell = Cells(Target.Row, [DataTable[Supplier]].Column) ' Column C, the same row as the updated cell
    Set materialCell = Cells(Target.Row, [DataTable[Material]].Column) ' Column D, the same row as the updated cell
    
    ' If supplier on this row is found in SpecialSupplierTable
    If IsInRange(supplierCell.Value, Range("SpecialSupplierTable")) Then
        ' Change fill color of supplier cell
        supplierCell.Interior.Color = 24567
        ' Add hyperlink to Alert Window Row of cell that changed.
        With ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(alertCell, Address:="https://www.automateexcel.com/excel/", TextToDisplay:="Checking needed")
            .Range.Font.Bold = True
            .Range.Font.Underline = False
            .Range.Font.Color = vbMagenta
        End With
    End If
    
    If IsInRange(materialCell.Value, Range("SpecialMaterialTable")) Then
        MsgBox "Please send an email to notify", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Quality Alert"
        materialCell.Interior.Color = 2552550  'Highlight the cells with Yellow Colour
    Else
        materialCell.Interior.Color = 16777215  'Clear the Colour in the cells if the value is nothing
    End If

End Function
```

The next two functions should not be placed in a sheet object code but in a Module,
So that they can be used for other sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsInRange(ByVal valueToFind, ByVal RangeToSearch As Range)
    ' If any cell in RangeToSearch = valueToFind, return True
    ' Else return False.
    IsInRange = True
    
    On Error GoTo EH
    x = RangeToSearch.Find(valueToFind)
    On Error GoTo 0

Exit Function
EH:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        ' this error is expected if valueToFind is not in RangeToSearch
        IsInRange = False
        Err.Clear
    Else
        ' Unexpected error.
        Err.Raise Number:=Err.Number, Source:=Err.Source, Description:=Err.Description
    End If
End Function


Public Function RangeAContainsRangeB(RangeA As Range, RangeB As Range)
' Returns True if RangeB is entirely within RangeA, else returns False.
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(RangeB, RangeA)
    RangeAContainsRangeB = False
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    ElseIf RangeB.Address = RangeA.Address Or rng.Address = RangeB.Address Then
        ' RangeB is completely within RangeA
        RangeAContainsRangeB = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! This is exactly what I'm looking for, I didn't know Format as Table could be used in such way. This is Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with the idea to store the supplier names in their own sheets. Your best bet is to encapsulate the logic that determines if a supplier requires special treatment into its own function. This will help to clean up your main method, and keeps all relevant logic grouped together.

I'll give an example below. I created a function `DoesSupplierRequireComment` that takes a supplier name, and returns `True/False` depending on whether the supplier is in column A of sheet `Variables`. Then, you can simply call the function from your main method, and act as needed. (In the example below, I call the function from `Sub Test` and simply show a message box). See if you can adapt the logic into your code, and follow up with any questions.

```
Function DoesSupplierRequireComment(supplierName As String) As Boolean
    Dim isRequired As Boolean
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    'Initialize variable to false
    isRequired = False
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Variables")
        'Determine the range that stores the variables.
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set searchRange = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        
        'Check if the passed in argument is found in the variables sheet
        If Not searchRange.Find(supplierName) Is Nothing Then
            isRequired = True
        End If
        
    End With
    
    DoesSupplierRequireComment = isRequired
End Function

Sub Test()
    If DoesSupplierRequireComment("LOL") Then
        MsgBox "Requires special treatment"
    Else
        MsgBox "Does Not"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using that way but I'm still stuck in the condition in the IF statement when calling the function as I wish to avoid updating the code when the list is updated. But your suggestion is great, I will use it for tidying up my code